# What is the purpose the different *Target properties?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dart

In the MouseEvent class there are multiple *Target events:

- [target](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/MouseEvent.html#target)
- [currentTarget](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/MouseEvent.html#currentTarget)
- [relatedTarget](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/MouseEvent.html#relatedTarget)

What is their purpose in the context of a MouseEvent?

Comment: proposing the addition of the "javascript" tag, as the question and answer essentially apply to both languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These properties are equivalent to the JavaScript mouse events. JavaScript events traverse the DOM (called "bubbling"). `target` is the object on which the event was originally dispatched on. `currentTarget` is the object on which your event handler has been attached.

**Example**

You have this HTML structure:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Entry 1</li>
  <li>Entry 2</li>
</ul>
```

and you add a click handler to the `<ul>` element (either via JavaScript or Dart, the concept is the same).

When you then click on "Entry 2", your click handler will be called (because the event "bubbles up" to it). `target` will be the `<li>` element, while `currentTarget` will be the `<ul>` element. Which one you have to use depends on what you want to do in your handler - for example, you could hide "Entry 2" itself by using `target`, or the whole list by using `currentTarget`.

The element referenced by `relatedTarget` depends on the type of your MouseEvent - a list can be found here: [event.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.relatedTarget). In the above example, it would be `null`, because click events don't have any related target.

Related MDN links:
[event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.currentTarget), 
[event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target)